# Is it possible to fade between two view background images?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if it's possible for some button to cause a fade from one background image to another? The following code I have results in an abrupt change from the current image, `background-image-1`, to the new image, `background-image-2`.

```
func buttonPressed() {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "background-image-2") {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {_ in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Though the accepted answer does work, I was finding *slight glitches* when toggling quickly between images. A similar method using `UIView.animateWithDuration` solves this:

```
func buttonPressed() {
    let oldImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background-image-1"))
    oldImageView.frame = view.frame
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"background-image-2"))
    newImageView.frame = view.frame
    newImageView.alpha = 0
    view.insertSubview(newImageView, aboveSubview: backgroundImageView)
    view.insertSubview(oldImageView, aboveSubview: newImageView)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        oldImageView.alpha = 0
        newImageView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { completed in
            self.backgroundImageView.image = newImage
            newImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            oldImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say `imageView` is the UIImageView you are using for your animation. `image1` is your original image. `image2` is the new image. Try this:

```
let crossFade: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
crossFade.duration = 1
crossFade.fromValue = image1.CGImage
crossFade.toValue = image2.CGImage
self.imageView.image = image2
self.imageView.layer.addAnimation(crossFade, forKey: "animateContents")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I attempted it in my **EDIT** section of the question. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Any suggestion why, please?

Comment: This is because your imageView was not created properly. In the view did appear method, set the imageView's center to the view's center and its size to the view's size.

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The background color is supposed to be an animatable property, but a pattern color must not work.

Do you actually want a pattern color, or are you using that in order to insert an image as the background of the view without using the repeating pattern?

Comment: I am using `pattern color:` in order to insert an image and the background of the view. The aim is to fade this image out and replace it with `background-image-2`. Thanks

Comment: Am I best just inserting it as a subview and animating it that way? e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026621/fade-animation-for-uiimages-in-swift